# Ошибка при устновке pyqt5 на mac m1

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, macos, m1

Ошибка при установке pyqt5
На Windows и линукс все работае
На mac с процессором m1 проблемы

Ошибка при установке

```
➜  ~ pip3 install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Downloading PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.2/3.2 MB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/gusfrink/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/gusfrink/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/gusfrink/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-h_h1xiiy/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-h_h1xiiy/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-h_h1xiiy/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 586, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-install-k5d58cfv/pyqt5_9a367d16b2ae4b6786e01c2b56937226/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-h_h1xiiy/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-h_h1xiiy/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-h_h1xiiy/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.1.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
➜  ~ pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (23.0.1)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.0.1
    Uninstalling pip-23.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.0.1
Successfully installed pip-23.1.1
➜  ~ pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (23.1.1)
➜  ~ pip3 install pyqt5        
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/gusfrink/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/gusfrink/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/gusfrink/.pyenv/versions/3.11.3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-qvg21qw_/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-qvg21qw_/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-qvg21qw_/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 586, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-install-1joibvea/pyqt5_0c841758f05b495a9c611b2f16de6cbf/project.py", line 68, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-qvg21qw_/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-qvg21qw_/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "/private/var/folders/wm/8l2pzrj57n3f9wc009934mk00000gn/T/pip-build-env-qvg21qw_/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```